# how to store and iterate through array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined

I can't access the field from the object since it throws the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'medicineId' of undefined
> **when i try the peice of code below,**

```
{medlist &&
  medlist.map(({medicineId, medicineName }) => (
    <li  key={medicineId} >
      <h1>{medicineName}</h1>
    </li>               
  ))
}
```

it gives me index.js:1 **Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.** even though the key is unique.but idk it gives me this unique key prop err cuz it is of type string.

Note that `medicineId` is of type string. and i tried to overcome this by changing that piece of code to,

```
{medlist &&
  medlist.map((med,idx) => (
    <li  key={idx} >
      <h1>{med.medicineName}</h1>
    </li>               
  ))
}
```

**and now i dont get the warning for unique key but, there is no display of the  tag *med.medicineName*.**
when i tried {console.log(med.medicineName)}
it is **undefined**

```
const fetchMedicineList = () =>{
  return axios.get('http://localhost:8080/medicine')
    .then(({data})=>{
      console.log(data[0].medicineName)//this prints the medicine name.
      return data;
    })
    .catch(err =>{
      console.error(err)
    });
}
but when i tried to store the object array inside usestate,
  const [medlist, setMedlist] = useState([])or**useState([{}])**
 useEffect(() => {
        fetchMedicineList().then(medicineList=>{
            setMedlist([...medlist,medicineList]);
            
        })
        
    }, [medlist])
and i cant print or access medlist[0].medicineName ,it says **undefine** what am i doing wrong here, thanks.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the API response without spread operation in setMedlist useState.

Check this

```
const initailValue =[];
const apiResponse =[{
'medicineName':'abc'
}]
const neWArr = [...initailValue,...apiResponse]
console.log(neWArr[0].medicineName)
```

for your problem try this,

```
  const [medlist, setMedlist] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMedicineList().then(medicineList=>{
        setMedlist([...medlist,...medicineList]);
        
    })
    
}, [medlist])
```

Answer (score 1):

This just checks whether array is present. So this will always be true.

```
[] ? true: false; //true always
```

So you ll have to check the length of it like this

```
[].length ? true: false // false
```

So use this

```
{medlist.length &&
  medlist.map(({medicineId, medicineName }) => (
    <li  key={medicineId} >
      <h1>{medicineName}</h1>
    </li>               
  ))
}
```